# error while running 'ros2 node list'

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got this error while running "ros2 node list"

```
File "/opt/ros/humble/bin/ros2", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.18.4', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')())
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2cli/cli.py", line 89, in main
    rc = extension.main(parser=parser, args=args)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2node/command/node.py", line 37, in main
    return extension.main(args=args)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2node/verb/list.py", line 38, in main
    node_names = get_node_names(node=node, include_hidden_nodes=args.all)
  File "/opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ros2node/api/__init__.py", line 60, in get_node_names
    node_names_and_namespaces = node.get_node_names_and_namespaces()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1122, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1464, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1166, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1182, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1354, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xmlrpc/client.py", line 668, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault 1: "<class 'rclpy._rclpy_pybind11.InvalidHandle'>:cannot use Destroyable because destruction was requested">
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411798/error-while-running-%27ros2-node-list%27/) by [harshahsrah](https://answers.ros.org/users/135348/harshahsrah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2023-01-25**:
welcome to ROS answers! Please consider formatting the error message (Ctrl-K) and specifying which version of ROS2 Humble you're running + how you installed (from source, debian package) and what platform you're one (e.g. Ubuntu Jammy). That way you can get faster and more specific help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might be an open bug as per [this issue](https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/issues/672).

Try:

```
ros2 daemon stop
ros2 daemon start
ros2 daemon status
```

---

Originally posted by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) with karma: 464 on 2023-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harshahsrah](https://answers.ros.org/users/135348/harshahsrah/) on 2023-01-26**:
It works now, thank you